# How to enable / disable a txt from a choice of a jquery radiobutton?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

I need to enable / disable a field according to the choice in a radiobutton

Validations:

> This field should only be active when the "Inactive" radio button is
>   selected

Follow code:

RadioButton:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label40" runat="server" Width="85px" Style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 17.2%;">DADOS</asp:Label>
                            <div style="border: solid 2px; height: 22px; width: 316px; margin-left: 50.4%; margin-top: -33px;">
   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbDados" name="rdbDados" CssClass="radioItens2" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Style="width: 319px;">
  <asp:ListItem Text="1º PEDIDO" Value="C" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="INATIVOS" Value="I"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
 </div>
```

Field that needs to be enabled / disabled:

```
 <asp:Label runat="server" Width="90">Nº MESES INATIVIDADE</asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="50px" ID="txtInatividade" name="inatividade"></asp:TextBox>
```

Jquery I tried to develop:

```
$("#<%=rdbDados.ClientID%>").change(function () {
           switch ($("#rdbDados input:radio:checked").val()) {
        case "I":
            $("#inatividade").prop("disabled", false);
            break;
        case "C":
            $("#inatividade").prop("disabled", true);
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: target the required element by Id not name.

Comment: Are your asp controls inside a `contentPanel` if they are to get the id of the elements you must include contentPanelId_idoftheElement. Basically, check the console for the ids of the your elements.

Comment: This is a javascript problem. please don't tag [tag:c#] if the problem is not related to it

Comment: If you click `<>` and post rendered HTML and your jQuery in a [mcve] we can answer much quicker. In any case no need for a switch for two values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want

```
$(function() {
  $("[name=rdbDados]").on("click",function() {  // assuming name of radios
    $("#txtInatividade").prop("disabled", this.value=="C");
  });
  $("#txtInatividade").prop("disabled", $("[name=rdbDados]:checked").val()=="C"); // handle load
});
```

In any case the switch is not needed

```
$("#idOfTextField").prop("disabled",$("#rdbDados input:radio:checked").val()=="C");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$("#inatividade").prop("disabled", false);
```

to

```
$("#txtInatividade").prop("disabled", false);
```

You're trying to access the input element via it's name property, rather than its ID.